# How can I save file in spark with dataset?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

What I need to do is to save a Dataset to Hadoop, my code:

```
val df = spark.read.textFile("hdfs://path/to/file")
              .flatMap(i => i.split("\\s+"))
              .groupBy("value").count.toDF("word","count")
              .write.json("hdfs://path/to/myjson.json")
```

but when I goto Hadoop, `myjson.json` is not a json file but a folder. When I read this folder with code like `spark.read.json("hdfs://path/to/myjson.json").show` again, it is exactly what I want.
My question is, how can I save a dataset to a file, not a folder ?

Comment: oh, thanks...so folder is normal..

Comment: You could technically coalesce() the dataframe into a single file, but I wouldn't do that for large datasets